# Get java program ready for release

Tags: java, compilation, package

I need help getting my java program ready for release. I have a program with three packages in each package are classes. Within one package is the class with main that requires all of the other classes when running. My question is how do I build this Java project so anyone can run it. The structure of the files is as follows:

- src/table/java files
- src/school/java files
- src/schoolSort/java files

The main is located in `schoolSort/Main.java` I have a Windows 7 set up and I have tried:

```
javac table/*.* school/*.* schoolSort/*.*
```

And this produced class files but the main file wont run. Help please. I am using Eclipse and have tried that too but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: Brandon, can you post your code so that we have some context? Also, please post any error messages you're getting and what commands you ran.

Comment: As well as can you elaborate more on "it didn't seem to work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, you can right click on your project and choose to export it as an executable jar. It will ask for your main class (through the run configuration you used) and you should be good to go from there.

Right click on project > Export > Java > Runnable Jar File

Comment: Just tried that and this created a single jar file which would do nothing when clicked on. When running from command line with java javatest.jar is says "Error: Could not find or load main class javatest.jar"

Comment: you need to use `java -jar javatest.jar`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create what is called an executable jar. This is the artifact that you will share with others.

[Here](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/java.tools.html) is the set of basic steps that you have to follow to create a jar

[Here](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html) is the set of steps to create an executable jar.

I'm sure eclipse will help you out with these steps, but I have not used it much.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, you can do File->Export->Java->Runnable JAR file...

Answer (score 0):

Check your packages are in classpath. If your packages are in classpath, you should try to use 'ant' to build your application.